# Label variables with lookup table and sjlabelled::set_label

Tags: r, spss, labeling

I need to label a lot of variables with sjlabelled::set_label. Here is a reproducable example and what already works:

```
library(data.table)
library(sjlabelled)

lookup <- data.table(id = paste0("q", 1:5),
                     question = paste0("qtext", 1:5))

data <- data.table(q1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   q2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   q3 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   q4 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   q5 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE))


data[, q1 := set_label(data[, q1], lookup[id == "q1", question])] 

get_label(data$q1)
```

So I am able to label specific variables if I call them with their id but I am struggling with the task if I want to "loop" through all variables. Tried with a for loop with no success.

The goal is to be able to export the datatable (or dataframe) as an SPSS file. If it works with other packages I would also be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set_label` directly on a dataframe.

```
library(sjlabelled)

data <- set_label(data, lookup$question[match(names(data), lookup$id)])

get_label(data)
#     q1       q2       q3       q4       q5 
#"qtext1" "qtext2" "qtext3" "qtext4" "qtext5"
```

Comment: I thought I could easily also do this with set_labels() and the answertext but I somehow cant. The different answer labels for one variable are split by a ";" like this "yes;no;dont know". Do you maybe have any idea how I can solve this too?
Tried to solve it with strsplit() but no luck.

Comment: Umm...Sorry, the question is not clear to me. Can you ask it as a new question with a similar example and expected output?

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886622/use-sjlabelledset-labels-with-lookup-table